# Exception Dates Array handling in Nodejs Cron

Tags: node.js, cron, node-cron

I'm using [Cron](https://github.com/ncb000gt/node-cron); a [nodejs package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cron#usage-basic-cron-usage) for cron job handling in NodeJs. Here's how I'm running a cron job:

```
var job = new CronJob({
  cronTime: '00 30 11 * * 1-5',
  onTick: function() {
    /*
     * Runs every weekday (Monday through Friday)
     * at 11:30:00 AM. It does not run on Saturday
     * or Sunday.
     */
  }
});
job.start();
```

It's running flawlessly but is there any **standard way** to handle exception dates array handling? For example here's my dates array of national holidays and I don't want to run my cron job on these days:

```
['28-01-2017', '1-05-2017', '14-08-2016', '15-09-2016', '16-09-2016']
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can not add exclusions to your cron job. You are much better off adding to your code the logic to not run on those days.

```
var job = new CronJob({
  cronTime: '00 30 11 * * 1-5',
  onTick: function() {
    var exclude = ['28-01-2017', '1-05-2017', '14-08-2016', '15-09-2016', '16-09-2016']
    if (exclude.indexOf(convertDate()) > -1) {
        console.log('dont run');
    } else {
        console.log('run');
    }
  }
});
job.start();

function convertDate() {
    var d = new Date();
    return [pad(d.getDate()), pad(d.getMonth()+1), d.getFullYear()].join('-');
}

function pad(s) {
    return (s < 10) ? '0' + s : s;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this is what I'm currently doing but if there's really not any standard way of handling those exception dates array then that should be the accepted answer.